# ubuntu 20.04.2 raspberry pi 4 kernel 5.10?

Tags: raspberrypi

I have understand wrong but ubuntu 20.04.2 haven't to got Kernel 5.10?

I am on rpi4 ubuntu desktop and if I do `uname -a` I get:
`5.4.0-1028-raspi #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 20 11:30:45 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

and
`lsb_release -a`
give:

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

what is my misunderstanding?

Best regards,
Leonardo

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has two kernel paths; the GA kernel (*the most stable*) will always be 5.4, and the HWE path follows the non-LTS path, and currently sits on Ubuntu 20.10's 5.8 kernel.  The HWE path won't move to the next kernel until after *hirsute* has been released, as that will become the next HWE kernel etc.

Comment: Its for stability rather than releasing the most bleeding edge kernel's and packages they hang back for reasons of stability.    Nothing worse than bleeding edge releases for Linux.

Comment: Ok thank you, I belive that from 20.04.2 HWE path was apply to all ubuntu version as a new canonical strategy... I have misunderstend.

Comment: sentence like that make be misunderstand: "Things have been changed recently. If you downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.2 or newer desktop version, HWE is enabled for you and you’ll get the new kernel along with the regular updates by default"

Comment: No Ubuntu does **not** default to HWE for all systems, Ubuntu Server for example defaults to using the GA kernel path unless the user selects the HWE during installation (the HWE kernels are included on installation media allowing user to change from the default GA kernel).  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop defaults to the HWE kernel now, but that's a single product.  If you install 20.04 for the pi, a common procedure is starting with Ubuntu Server (so GA kernel is used) then run `desktopify` which converts it to desktop (or flavor) but it remains GA (if that has changed in last month, I'm unaware)